# В чем ошибка в приведенном коде?

Tags: c

подскажите в чем ошибка

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int size = 12,i;
    float a[size],b[size],max=a[0],min=a[0];

    for(i = 0;i < size;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter %d element = ",i);
        scanf("%f",&a[i]);      
    }

    for(i = 0;i < size;i++)
    {   
     if(a[i]<min)
     {
        min=a[i];
     }
     if(a[i]>max)
     {
        max=a[i];
     }  
    }
    float sum = min+max;
    for(i = 0; i <size ; i ++)
    {
        if(a[i]>0)
        {
            b[i]=a[i]/sum;
        }
        else
        {
            b[i]=a[i];
        }
    }
    printf("Pochatkovui masuv \n\n");
    for(i = 0; i <size ; i ++)
    {
        printf("%d Element = %.2f \n",i,a[i]);
    }
        printf("Otrumanui  masuv \n\n");
    for(i = 0; i <size ; i ++)
    {
        printf("%d Element = %.2f \n",i,b[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
    printf("Minimum = %.2f \n",min);    
    printf("Maximum = %.2f \n",max); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Письмо в Академию наук: Товарищи учёные! Вот уже третий год у меня в подполье происходит подземный стук. Объясните мне, что это значит!

Comment: Ваша программа тоже производит подземный стук? Или не устраивает что-то другое?

Comment: Вы так и не указали: в чем у вас эта самая "ошибка" и какое желаемое поведение программы.

Answer (score 0):

А чем компилируете?

Мне кажется, что вам бы стоило заменить вот эту строчку

```
int size = 12,i;
```

на две:

```
int i;
#define size  12
```